# Wrong N times matrix rotation

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a task to rotate 2D matrix R`times [image] what has n columns and m rows. Rotation should be in anti-clockwise direction.

The problems with my code below:

1. Looks like the `StepValuesOperation` method wrongly get or set values from matrix. I've already break a head to find out where is a problem.
2. Is it possible to rotate values without moving it into separated array?

About the code:

- I have and a console application, which randomly initialize the matrix size, its values and count of rotation by `InitializeParams` method;
- I get the count of iterations of matrix and for each get an array of values of the current iteration by `StepValuesOperation` method;
- From the count of rotations, which could be greater than the count of digits in the current iteration, I get `rotCount` by `mod` operation.
- Then rotate values by the `RorateValues` method and move it back to matrix by `StepValuesOperation`

  ```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      int m, r, n;
      long[,] matrix;
      InitializeParams(out n, out m, out r, out matrix);

      Console.WriteLine("Rotation times: " + r);
      Console.WriteLine("Input matrix:");
      PrintMatrix(matrix);

      Console.WriteLine();
      int deep = Math.Min(m, n) / 2;
      for (int step = 0; step < deep; step++)
      {
          List<long> oldArr = new List<long>((n + m) * 2);
          StepValuesOperation(false, step, oldArr, matrix);

          int perim = oldArr.Count;
          int rotCount = perim < r ? r % perim : r;
          if (rotCount != 0 && rotCount != perim)
          {
              long[] newArr = new long[perim];
              Console.WriteLine($"Rest rotation count {rotCount} from {r} with perimeter {perim}");
              Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", oldArr));

              RorateValues(rotCount, newArr, oldArr);

              Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", newArr));
              StepValuesOperation(true, step, newArr, matrix);
          }

          Console.WriteLine();
      }


      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Output matrix:");
      PrintMatrix(matrix);
      Console.ReadLine();
  }

  private static void RorateValues(int rotCount, IList<long> newArr, IList<long> oldArr)
  {
      int perim = oldArr.Count;
      for (int i = 0; i < perim; i++)
      {
          int pos = i + rotCount;
          if (pos >= perim)
          {
              pos -= perim;
          }

          newArr[pos] = oldArr[i];
      }
  }
  ```

### Random initialization parameters of the matrix

```
    private static void InitializeParams(out int n, out int m, out int r, out long[,] matrix)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        n = 4;//rand.Next(2, 7) * 2;
        m = 6;//rand.Next(1, 5) * 2;
        r = rand.Next(1, 10000);
        matrix = new long[n, m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = rand.Next(i + j, i + j + n * 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Move out of or into array the values of matrix

```
    private static void StepValuesOperation(bool initialized, int step, IList<long> arr, long[,] matrix)
    {
        int sizeI = matrix.GetLength(0) - step;
        int sizeJ = matrix.GetLength(1) - step;
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = step; i < sizeI; i++, pos++)
        {
            if (!initialized)
                arr.Add(matrix[i, step]);
            else
                matrix[i, step] = arr[pos];
        }
        for (int j = step; j < sizeJ; j++, pos++)
        {
            if (!initialized)
                arr.Add(matrix[sizeI - 1, j]);
            else
                matrix[sizeI - 1, j] = arr[pos];
        }
        for (int i = sizeI - 1; i > step; i--, pos++)
        {
            if (!initialized)
                arr.Add(matrix[i, sizeJ - 1]);
            else
                matrix[i, sizeJ - 1] = arr[pos];
        }
        for (int j = sizeJ - 1; j > step; j--, pos++)
        {
            if (!initialized)
                arr.Add(matrix[step, j]);
            else
                matrix[step, j] = arr[pos];
        }
    }

    private static void PrintMatrix(long[,] matrix)
    {
        int n = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int m = matrix.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

My wrong output:

> Rotation times: 9402
>
> Input matrix:
>
> 29 3 24 9 39 28
>
> 9 38 31 20 24 44
>
> 27 27 38 31 10 37
>
> 32 15 25 40 40 42
>
> Output matrix:
>
> 44 37 42 42 40 40
>
> 28 20 24 10 10 25
>
> 39 38 27 27 31 15
>
> 24 3 29 9 27 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the rotation can be done **In Place**. I am not a **C#** programmer so I stick to **C++** syntax which is pretty close.

1. **I would create function that rotate rectangle circumference**

   It can be done in place with single temp value (exactly as **jackmott** suggest). something like this:

   ```
   void matrix_rect_ccw(int **a,int x0,int y0,int xs,int ys)
       {
       int x,y,xx,yy,x1,y1,a0;
       // prepare constants
       x1=x0+xs-1;
       y1=y0+ys-1;
       // rotate CCW
       a0=a[x0][y0];   // store first element to temp
       x=x0; y=y0;     // destination
       xx=x; yy=y;     // source
       for (xx++;x<x1;x++,xx++) a[x][y]=a[xx][yy]; xx--;
       for (yy++;y<y1;y++,yy++) a[x][y]=a[xx][yy]; yy--;
       for (xx--;x>x0;x--,xx--) a[x][y]=a[xx][yy]; xx++;
       for (yy--;y>y0;y--,yy--) a[x][y]=a[xx][yy]; yy++;
       a[x0][y0+1]=a0; // restore last element from temp
       }
   ```

   where `x0,y0` is upper left corner of rectangle and `xs,ys` its size. The `a[][]` is the matrix. No need for matrix size parameter if the rectangle is fully inside...

   To debug you can instead rotating filling the loop with increasing index for example:

   ```
   int i=0;
   for (xx++;x<x1;x++,xx++,i++) a[x][y]=i; xx--;
   for (yy++;y<y1;y++,yy++,i++) a[x][y]=i; yy--;
   for (xx--;x>x0;x--,xx--,i++) a[x][y]=i; xx++;
   for (yy--;y>y0;y--,yy--,i++) a[x][y]=i; yy++;
   ```

   or:

   ```
   int i=0;
   for (xx++;x<x1;x++,xx++,i++) a[xx][yy]=i; xx--;
   for (yy++;y<y1;y++,yy++,i++) a[xx][yy]=i; yy--;
   for (xx--;x>x0;x--,xx--,i++) a[xx][yy]=i; xx++;
   for (yy--;y>y0;y--,yy--,i++) a[xx][yy]=i; yy++;
   ```

   So you can check if the iterations goes through the right elements in the right order. This is the result for `(x,y)` called for all loops:

   ```
      0   1   2   3   4
     13   0   1   2   5
     12   5   4   3   6
     11  10   9   8   7
   ```

   This is the `(xx,yy)` case:

   ```
     13   0   1   2   3
     12   5   0   1   4
     11   4   3   2   5
     10   9   8   7   6
   ```
2. **do a `for` loop to rotate whole matrix**

   simply call the rotate from **#1** for all loops. And also the whole thing `step` times. Something like this:

   ```
   void matrix_ccw(int **a,int xs,int ys,int step)
       {
       int i,j,n;
       // smallest size / 2 ... number of loops to rotate
       n=xs; if (n<ys) n=ys; n/=2;
       for (j=0;j<step;j++)
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
         matrix_rect_ccw(a,i,i,xs-i-i,ys-i-i);
       }
   ```

   You should handle the CW/CCW separately just by changing the for loops order in the **#1**. Also you should bound step to modulo loop size. If the step is larger then half of the loop size then convert it to the opposite direction rotation to speed up the process. This is the input matrix I tested on:

   ```
     11  12  13  14  15
     21  22  23  24  25
     31  32  33  34  35
     41  42  43  44  45
   ```

   And this is rotated by `step=1` in **CCW** direction:

   ```
     12  13  14  15  25
     11  23  24  34  35
     21  22  32  33  45
     31  41  42  43  44
   ```

   You should also handle invalid matrix sizes for rotation to avoid confusion in future use...

**[Notes]**

The rotation can be done also without the step looping the whole thing by copying directly with `step` offset but for that you need to store `a0[step]` values instead of single one complicating this all a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could simplify it by representing the outer points as one circularly linked list and the inner points as another.  Then it becomes pretty easy to rotate them in place with a single temp variable.  If performance is a concern you can use a 1 dimensional array for each, and just handle the edge cases at the start and end.

edit - looks like the algorithm has to be more general than that, which would mean "n" circularly linked lists, which might not be any simpler.